# Wiring 434mhz transmitter to Explorer Hat

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to hookup this transmitter module http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/TWS-BS-3_433.92MHz_ASK_RF_Transmitter_Module_Data_Sheet.pdf to the Raspberry Pi Explorer HAT...

As you can see from the data sheet, pin 3 is the data input. The HAT provides outputs which sink to ground when they are ON...

I've got an LED switching on and off by connecting 5V to it's input and then connecting it's output to one of the HAT's outputs (which alternate between sinking to ground and not) but I can't get the transmitter working despite trying different wiring configurations. For the record, the transmitter does work and can be seen to be working, if I simply connect another 5V to the chip's data input.

My question is: how do I wire up the RF transmitter's input pin to one of the Explorer Hat (github.com/pimoroni/explorer-hat) 's output pins?

The output pins do not provide voltage, they only sink to ground when they are turned ON (programmatically - I've got this bit covered, I'm just unsure of the wiring).

Comment: What is your question and what is this "HAT" you refer to?

Comment: @Andyaka: Obviously the mindreading hat you should have on when trying to answer questions.

Comment: @PlasmaHH hey where can I buy one from but I guess you knew I was going to ask that eh?

Comment: @Andyaka: Sure, just give me a few minutes to finish marking up the prices due to increase in demand

Comment: Wire an antenna round the brim, use stiff wire and you can hang the corks off it.

Comment: Oh you guys. My question is how do I wire up the RF transmitter's input pin to one of the Explorer Hat (https://github.com/pimoroni/explorer-hat) 's output pins. The output pins do not provide voltage, they only sink to ground when they are turned ON (programmatically - I've got this bit covered, I'm just unsure of the wiring).

Comment: We were all beginners once. Be nice.

Comment: @JimbobMcBradders: especially as a beginner you should be able to realize that everyone only knows a fraction of the products out there, and thus you have to provide datasheets.

Comment: I have provided a data sheet. There is documentation, and specifically about the outputs I am wanting to connect to here: https://github.com/pimoroni/explorer-hat/blob/master/documentation/Function-reference.md#output - I'm not really sure what more information I can provide.

Comment: "When you turn Explorer HAT/pHAT outputs on ( logic HIGH ) it will sink current to ground. Be mindful of this when connecting to the output driver- you'll need to connect your device to a voltage supply, and then to the output pin"

Comment: ^ I don't know how to do this. The RF chip is already connected to 5V through pin 3. Pin 1 is connected to ground. Pin 2... Well... This is where I'm stuck, connecting this to the HAT output in the correct fashion.

Comment: Maybe a pull-up resistor then??

Comment: Thanks jbord, I think you're probably right. Somebody else recommended a transistor, too. I'll do some research into these two options.

Comment: Well, I answered my own question. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Connect pin one of the RF chip to ground.
Connect pin three of the RF chip to +5v.
Connect pin two to both one of the outputs on the HAT *and* to +5v (via a resistor for the +5v).

The connection to the HAT output should come *between* the +5v and pin two of the RF chip, so when the switch is ON, the signal goes to to ground and not to the RF chip's input.

Note that this setup has the effect of reversing the switch behavior so that when the switch is OFF, the RF chip will transmit ON.